# How to manually add nexus-maven-repository-index.gz to Intellij?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I've downloaded `nexus-maven-repository-index.gz` file from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.index/ . How can I manually add this index file to the Intellij?